# Windows 8 Phone periodic task not running

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

I went through the following documentation to create a background periodic task:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202941(v=vs.105).aspx

For some reason, I never see it running. (In the sense, the OnInvoke() method in the class SchedulerTaskAgent.cs never got invoked)

With debugger on, I was able to invoke the method using:

```
if(DEBUG_AGENT)
    ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
#endif
```

It ran fine every 60 seconds. I saw the debug statements I added to OnInvoke() getting printed every minute (60 seconds).

Then I commented out the above lines to test to see if OnInvoke() gets called by the OS at times (say like every 30 minutes or so).

It was never called. I connected the phone to my Windows computer and the phone was fully charged, but was not connected to Wifi, but to the cellular network.

I am not sure as to understand why it was not triggered. I attempted the whole day yesterday (at least 6 to 8 times waiting between 30 minutes and an hour).

How do I test periodic task in the real world scenario where I can't use: ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(...)

My phone was simply idling and the phone I use is exclusive for testing (I don't have any apps running in the background,the cellular network signal was really good, with battery up to 100%).

Also the periodic task is just going to print some messages and not going to do any network or resource-intense activity.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Same problem here. No idea how to search for errors

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a pound sign in front of the if.
eg.

```
#if(DEBUG_AGENT)
ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(periodicTaskName, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
#endif
```